# Why does wavelength coherence affect diffusion?

Tags: laser, diffusion, photon-emission, coherence

Not to be confused with the relationship between wavelength and photon localization.

But, laser light is is able to stay concentrated over a vast distance, much more so than every-day lamp light. One of the biggest differences in laser light is that the output is concentrated at only one wavelength with greater coherence between the oscillations of individual photons. Why does this aspect allow the beam of laser light to stay focused?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a point source on a piece of paper that emits a 2D circular wave outwards in all directions. The magnitude of such a wave can be defined at each point along the circumference of circle with a radius r =c*t. In other words we can say, along a circle with r =c*t centered at the point source, the magnitude varies as A*cos(wx) where x is a point on the circumference and w is the frequency, an integer.

The source has the ability to emit waves with  different frequencies. When it emits these different frequency waves at the same time, there exists constructive and destructive interference seen by an increase/decrease in magnitude along the circumference of the summed waves. However, the narrower the line width (variations of frequency) of this point source (laser), the more coherent and more constructive interference the beam will see. Thus it will effectively “stay focused”.

Comment: Can you not simply refract a single frequency and scatter it in all directions to emulate diffusion? There are all kinds of partial coherence interactions with minerals that can accomplish that. My guess is this has something more to do with how laser light is constructed. If you shine an LED light of only a very specific color, like red, it still diffuses in all directions.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean, but lasers are never made up of a single frequency. Beams diverge due to interference effects and scattering in the medium it travels in

Comment: What you said contradicts what literally every single online source I ever found about it says.

Comment: What contradicts everything?

Comment: Your statement that laser light is never made up of a single frequency.

Comment: That statement is correct. Idk your sources, but google laser line width or just general lasing physics

Comment: No I did google laser before posting this question. and google disagrees with you.

Comment: Idk what sources you’re reading man, but it’s a fundamental consequence of the energy position uncertainty relation in quantum mechanics. If you google laser line width, you’ll find a more helpful explanation

Comment: Nope I specifically cleared that up in the first post, I specifically stated "Not to be confused with the relationship between wavelength and photon localization."